# TensorFlow - Removing name scope when plotting summary?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm currently building my operations twice, once for training and once for validation with the `variable_scope` set to have `reuse=True` to ensure I've only got one set of weights to train.

To organize the operations though, I wrap the operation building call for training in a

```
with tf.name_scope='train':
```

and similarly do the same for validation. This allows me to create a few summary hooks easily, by simply calling

```
tf.summary.merge(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, scope='train'))
```

at the end to get summaries for either the training graph or the validation graph and save these summaries with the appropriate summary saver.

Unfortunately, this also means that a scalar in the training summaries is not displayed on the same plot as the equivalent scalar in the validation (because they are in different name scopes).

Is there either a way to remove the name scope before saving the summary, or a different method of wrapping the summaries for a specific case together without applying the name scope to begin with? Or do I need to manually keep track of the summaries for each case?

**EDIT:**

Just clarify, my code looks something like:

```
with tf.name_scope('train'):
    create_network()  # Summaries create in here.
with tf.name_scope('validation'):
    create_network(reuse=True)  # More summaries in here.
train_summaries = tf.summary.merge(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, scope='train'))
validation_summaries = tf.summary.merge(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, scope='validation'))
# Down here, create the summary saver hooks, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is done in the [multi-GPU CIFRA-10 example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L92) to get rid of unnecessary prefixes:

```
loss_name = re.sub('%s_[0-9]*/' % cifar10.TOWER_NAME, '', l.op.name)
tf.summary.scalar(loss_name, l)
```

Perhaps you can report the scalar with the same name from both `validation` as well as the `training` part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But unless I'm missing something, I don't think your solution works for my case. I clarified what might code somewhat looks like above, since I'm not sure I was the most clear. That is, the summary was already created in the name scope. Also, the name scope is needed at that point, since I need it to easily get the summaries for the separate cases. Without it, I can't simply grab the whole set of summaries (without manually marking each one in the code as in a collection).

Comment: @golmschenk You can keep the global lookup _as well as_ report this extra scalar separately.

Comment: I see, if I understand what you're saying, I can use the global lookup outside the name scope to grab the values I want to add to the summary. However, this would still require me individually specify each such value I want to do this to, right?

Comment: @golmschenk I'm afraid something along those lines may be needed for all scalars you want plotted on the same part of the board. However, I have very limited experience with Tensorboard, so other easier ways may still exist.